# I can't get this simple calculation right

Tags: c#

I have a very small windows form application that calculates the storage cost for a warehouse depending on the amount of deliveries per year and presents the result in form of a chart.
It's doing what it's supposed to do, but there is just one little flaw.

[image]

There is 13 columns in the first bit and then there is 12 every other time.
I want it to always be 12.

I've been trying to reorder some lines of code, it looks like it's all ok, I'm probably just missing one line of code but can't figure it out

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace StorageCost
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public static int throughPot = 52000;

            public static int weekly = 1000;
            public static int weeklyPalletCost = 180;
            public static int deliveries = 2;

            public int storageCost;

            public static int x = 0;

            public static int currentPot = throughPot / deliveries;

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Calculate();
            }

            private void Calculate()
            {
                currentPot = throughPot / deliveries;
                storageCost = 0;
                x = 0;
                chart1.Series[0].Points[0].YValues[0] = currentPot + 4000;

                for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++)
                {
                    currentPot -= weekly;

                    if (x>= 51 / deliveries)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        currentPot = throughPot / deliveries;
                    }

                    chart1.Series[0].Points[i].YValues[0] = currentPot + 4000;

                    storageCost += currentPot * weeklyPalletCost;
                    x++;

                }

                cost.Text = "Total storage cost: £" + storageCost / 100;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
                chart1.Update();
            }

            private void deliveriesUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                deliveries = (int)deliveriesUpDown.Value;
                Calculate(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the full code.
all I need basically is to get the same result in the beginning as from 13th column onwards

any help will be much appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not tested it but I think the problem might be that you always divide `int` by `int`. This makes you loose a lot of precision. Try replacing `x / y` with `(x*100 / y) / 100` and see if that makes a difference. If not, try using `float` or `double` for the calculations. You can still round them to `int` after the calculations.

Comment: Looks like a problem to me, that you can typically analyze very well with the debugger and step-by-step following of the execution path (F10/F11 in Visual Studio).

Comment: @Joelius changed everything to floats. still the same result.

Answer (score 4):

It was because the first column was done outside of the for loop!
after commenting this out

```
            //currentPot = throughPot / deliveries;
            //storageCost = 0;
            //x = 0;
            //chart1.Series[0].Points[0].YValues[0] = currentPot + 4000;
```

and changing the loop to `for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++)`
I got it to work as expected.

Thanks @Grimm 
I didn't know about this F11, F10 thing. This helped me a lot!

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to suggest.  Well done.  You can mark your own answer as accepted if you get no better ones!

Comment: I get "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". 
Thanks for your time :)